# Добавление элемента в БД в приложении JavaServer Faces 2.x CRUD

Tags: java, netbeans, crud

Воспользовался [руководством](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud_ru.html#), в целом все работает, но есть проблемы с созданием новых записей в таблицу. А именно - в моей таблице есть столбец id, который является первичным ключом и генерируется автоматически. В связи с чем возникает проблема - при создании нового элемента в моем приложении - программа запрашивает, что писать в столбец id. Если ничего не написать - попросит написать, если что-либо написать - также не завершит создание элемента, заявив "Transaction aborted". Что мне нужно исправить, чтобы программа оставила id-столбец в покое и он сам себе спокойно автозаполнялся?

Answer (score 1):

Здравсвуйте. Попробуйте так:

1. Добавить в класс сущности строку `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
2. Классе контролера добавьте функцию `create()` и добавьте туда строку `current.setId(0);`

[Источник](https://blogs.oracle.com/javajungle/entry/netbeans_jsf_and_mysql_primary)

Comment: А можете подробнее пояснить - куда именно эту строку добавлять? А то вроде ругается куда ни поставь.